# Using Mvvm How to get data in Datagrid wpf?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I want to execute the data grid and enter the data in the row of the data grid and save the data in the database when I press the button. How do I get the new Data Grid row in the MVVM format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend creating a form that specifically adds data into the database then refresh the item source of the data grid.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding ProductCollection}"  Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="DATE ADDED" Binding="{Binding DateAdded}" Width="Auto" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="PRODUCT ID" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="PRODUCT NAME" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="CATEGORY" Binding="{Binding CategoryName}" Width="*" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Sample Form:

```
<StackPanel MinWidth="250" MaxWidth="250">
    <TextBox  Margin="10" Text="{Binding NewId,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  MinHeight="38" />
    <TextBox  Margin="10" Text="{Binding NewName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  MinHeight="38"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding InsertCommand}">Save</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

For the ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<ProductModel> ProductCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ProductModel>();
```

After inserting the data into the database, just create a new product object using the data from the form then add it to the collection(ProductCollection). It will automatically refresh the datagrid.

```
ProductModel item = new ProductModel();
item.id = NewId;
item.Name = NewName;
ProductCollection.Add(item);
```

In the context of refreshing the data, I do not recommend this method of creating an object then insert it to the collection rather than clearing the collection then re-retrieve the data from the database if your program has multiple users.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. But is there any way to enter data directly into the data grid instead of creating a form to enter it?